# Set field value in retrofit

Tags: java, android, rest, interface, retrofit

Is it possible to set the field value within the Retrofit interface?  For example, one of my fields is the name of the command.

```
@FormUrlEncoded @POST("/main") void getUsers(
        @Field("command") String command,
        @Field("user_key") String userKey,
        ResponseCallback responseCallback
);
```

So in this case I've set up a function called getUsers, but this requires me to pass in the "command" name function every time. This would be unnecessary, as every time I called this getUsers function, I would want to use the same command value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a wrapper over this function in your RestAdapter class.
something like this

```
public static void getUsers(String userKey, ResponseCallback callback) {
// call this api here 
API.getUsers(userKey, "defaultCammand", callback);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is what I thought I would need.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `RequestInterceptor` in which you `addEncodedQueryParam` to the request , here's and example :

```
RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
  @Override
  public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
    request.addEncodedQueryParam("command", "some command"); // this is the trick
  }
};

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
  .setEndpoint("https://api.github.com")
  .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor) // don't forget to set the interceptor
  .build();
```

PS : this will add the parameter to all requests, to add parameter to a specific ones you to create a constant and pass this constant for those requests ( using a wrapper method )

Comment: Thanks for your help. As you said, this works for all requests, but I wanted to add a command per function call, so a wrapper is needed. Thanks again for your help.